# xcode4 archive/ipa problem

Tags: xcode4, archive, ipa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4 Archive Version Unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332115/xcode-4-archive-version-unspecified)

Hi,

I'm archiving an application for iPad adhoc deployment but when I try to share the archive, the option for ipa construction is not available. The application I'm trying to deploy was created using XCode 3. It worked perfectly fine over there.

My problem seems to be, that the created archive has two missing values. The organizer shows the value of "version" as "unspecified" and the value "identifier" is empty. I tried setting this values in my info.plist and in the Info-tab in the project settings. None of it worked.

So why are these values not correctly set?

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Missing version and identifier]

Comment: Exactly the same problem! Have you found any solution?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how it is not available? Just wondering if you are looking for it in the wrong place.

Comment: Exactly the same problem! Have you found any solution?

Comment: For the record this is not a duplicate of the 'Possible Duplicate' item.

Answer (score 9):

Your Xcode project probably references one or more other Xcode projects for shared libraries that your project requires.  Go through the Xcode projects for each of those shared libraries, and set each target's "Skip Install" build setting to "Yes".  Then rebuild your archive.  Organizer should now let you create your .ipa.