# Problem linking existing projects in xcode4

Tags: ios, xcode4

I want to link two existing library projects to my new project in xcode4. I've tried 2 solutions so far.

1. Adding two projects inside the new one.
2. Creating a workspace and adding all three projects in it. 
   But in both cases when I build, the header files are not found by compiler. I've tried adding "Target Dependencies" in "Build Phases" of my project and adding library files (.a) to "Link Binary With Libraries" but nothing works.
   After reading other posts on this issue I found out that I have to configure "Search Paths" for the project but I don't know how to. Because I've tried some solutions but they don't work for me so I'm surely missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Xcode 4 Project Fails to compile a static library

> Related question: [Xcode 4 can't locate public header files from static library dependancy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5543854/89035)
> Related question: [“lexical or preprocessor issue file not found ” in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-file-not-found-in-xcode-4)

**Errors might include;** missing header files, "lexical or preprocessor issue"

Solutions:

1. Check the "user header paths" are correct
2. Set "Always search user paths" to YES
3. Create a group call "Indexing headers" in your project and drag the headers to this group, *DO NOT* add to any targets when prompted.

Comment: and what should be "user header paths"?

Comment: @Anila Set the "User Header Path" to the location of the header files the compiler can't find.