# Jenkins dont see 3-rd party libs in iOS project

Tags: ios, jenkins

I have a iOS project in which a included static library `myLibrary.a` with headers.
One of its headers (`MyHeader.h`) I included to `MyProject-Prefix.pch`

But when I run Jenkins to build my project, I get error:

```
#import "MyHeader.h" file not found
```

What the reason of this ? how to fix that ?

Comment: Is this header in your *headers search path*? If so, is the path relative to your project folder?

Comment: where to look headers search path ?

Comment: Check http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/

Comment: Check out this question. It has a lot of solutions to missing header issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependancy.