# static library file not found on Archiving The Project

Tags: ios, objective-c

## import "IQKeyboardManager.h"

static library file  **IQKeyboardManager** not found while archive,
But Project is build and run successfully.

Comment: where to import this library and get this error ?

Comment: Under "Link Binary With Libraries" add static library that created by me from another project and want to add that project in my sub project.

Comment: Project Run and Build successfully in device or Simulator?

Comment: I set User Header Search Path : $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) as recursive

Comment: yes @Venkat Only problem while archiving

Comment: How did you use them? By manually or CocoaPods?

Comment: By manually @Himanth

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build settings and add **$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/exactPathToHeaders** to **Header Search Path**. Try to archive again. It should solve your problem.

If you still face problem find following links

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependency/10159481#10159481)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808853/why-is-a-static-librarys-header-file-not-found-for-archiving)

Comment: Try adding through Cocoapods