# iOS Static Lib Configuration - Imports within exported header not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I have static lib project from which I am exporting a single header file. I used this [Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW4) to configure the static library. Twice ;) In the same workspace I have another project which links to the static library. I used the above mentioned guide to configure this as well.

I have no issues building the static library. However, when I attempt to build the application which links to my static library the static lib build fails. It complains that it cannot locate header files referenced in the exported header.

Why would this be? Is my static library being built in a different location when building the linking project?

Can anyone give me some tips to trouble shoot this? I am following the documentation to a "T".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "Copy Headers" in you Build Phases of your target.

[image]

Comment: I can do that.. but the documentation specifically states to delete this build phase as it is not compatible with archiving

Comment: I tried.. Still no dice

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and trial and error I stumbled upon the following SO question. Scroll to "gdavis'" answer (he/she has the most ++'s). I'm thinking I should create Gist to store this information for myself and the world;) while giving the contributor credit. I love me some iOS but cannot wrap my head around why Apple cannot simplify the process to reference files and resources. Even MS has that worked out. Anyways I hope this person's answer is as much help to someone else as it was for me.

[Best answer ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543854/xcode-4-cant-locate-public-header-files-from-static-library-dependancy)

Thanks,

Nick