# Compilation error in Xcode, subliminal.h not found

Tags: xcode, subliminal

After following the steps to install Subliminal via git submodule, I receive an error when trying to compile that says:

`Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Subliminal/Subliminal.h file not found`

This issue occurs in the app delegate file, after I add in #import . If I use Command + Click the header, I am lead to the header file. However, during compile, Xcode gives the above error.

*Edit: It's not libSubliminal, but I still can't figure out what goes wrong

*Import code is `#import <Subliminal/Subliminal.h>`

Comment: Show your actual `#import` code please

Comment: The import code I am using is `#import <Subliminal/Subliminal.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a nice adventure with StackOverflow, I found this solution:

[Xcode 4 can't locate public header files from static library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855606/4210658)

So far it has worked for me (I have managed to compile and run a default test).