# Mac Ogre Xcode project can't find headers

Tags: include, osx-lion, ogre

While trying to get the template Xcode 4 ogre project to work, the build fails because it can't find OgreCamera.h.

I've installed Ogre to /opt/local/lib/OGRE, and specified that as the Ogre SDK location when creating the Xcode 4 project.

Needless to say, the header and framework include paths in the project settings point exactly to where all the header files are, yet not one of them can be found. I've tried commenting out the include of OgreCamera.h, and upon trying to run, the next include, OgreEntity.h, cannot be found. Commenting that out and running again, the next include can't be found, and so on (these includes are in OgreFramework.h.

I don't understand why these headers, which clearly exist when I go look for them in the Finder or Terminal, can't be found by the project, even when I specify their full path like this:

```
#include </opt/local/lib/OGRE/lib/release/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.7.4/Headers/OgreCamera.h>
```

Did I somehow install the Ogre SDK incorrectly? (I copied it from the DMG into place…)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found partial success by following rjstelling's answer from this thread:

[why can't Xcode find this header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634071/why-cant-xcode-find-this-header-file)

That solved the OgreCamera.h include issues, but now I'm stuck on including the boost libraries. They are not picked up on the search paths, or in the Indexing group as suggested in the thread above.

Basically it looks like a bug in XCode4 that has to be worked around until a patch is released. There is also more information here:

[Compile, Build or Archive problems with Xcode 4 (and dependencies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584317/compile-build-or-archive-problems-with-xcode-4-and-dependancies)