# WorkSpace Vs Project Vs Target in Xcode

Tags: xcode, project, target, workspace

As I am new to Xcode, I do not understand clearly how Xcode organizes workspaces and projects. By using Google, I believe the following:

1. A workspace contains many projects.
2. Project contains many Targets
3. A project should have at least one target.

Are all of the above statements are true?

4. If i have one class called (login.h,login.m,login.xib) in my project, can I use the same login file in different targets?
5. Can i use the same file in different Projects.

If there is a tutorial or other articles that explain, please let me know of them.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html)?

Comment: Not yet will go through it

Comment: @trojanfoe i just read it.i think All of my statements are correct.if i need to maintain same login class with some modifications for each target.how can i achieve it

Comment: Add a constant to the build settings of each target (for example `SOME_TARGET=1` or `LOGIN_BEHAVIOUR=X`) and then test that within the source file (i.f `#if LOGIN_BEHAVIOUR == X .... #endif`).

Comment: k.i want to know clearly.My requirement is i have 10 targets with slight change in Appdelegate.m file. (i.e. A string StrAppId for each target varies).For this shall i need to use differenet Appdelgate files for eact target?

Comment: Your question is already answered over [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Project vs. Xcode Workspace - Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences)