# Custom build conditions and Warnings Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, build, warnings

My iOS Project has a compulsion that every class a developer make must be prefixed by "SYV". I have to add build setting that if any class does not follow this convention it should be shown as a warning in Xcode.

I am not sure where to start or its even possible. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but needs some work which I'm not sure is worth it. How many classes will be in the project? If it's not a large project, manual code review should do the job. However, if you want to follow your plan, here's what you can do:

**Approach 1:** Put all your classes in one folder (or subfolders). Given that you only put one class in each file, and the class is named after the file, you can have a very simple script that just validates all file names, maybe recursively, if you want to have some structure.

**Approach 2:** Use [Xcode Build Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Build%20Rule.html): Specify a new rule for `*.m` files (and maybe `*.h`, too, if you want to be sure). As this overwrites the default rule (compiling the files) and I don't know an easy solution to execute the default rule afterwards, I'd suggest you create an extra target for validation only, which doesn't need to compile. You then need a custom script that parses the source files, finds class `@implementation`s (assuming every class is implemented, I can't see a reason to check `@interface`s directly, but I may be missing something here), and validates their names. You could probably get away with some regex, or fully parse the files using [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html). If you implement the validation in a C-based (C, C++, Objective-C,...) command-line tool that is called from your build rule script, you can use this to generate warnings that show up in Xcode:

```
// casts are only added as hints to the types used
printf("%s:%d: warning: %s", (string)symbolName, (int)lineNumber, (string)text);
```

I haven't found a way to generate warnings from bash scripts directly though. More Infos on build rules can be found [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/xcode-build-rules/).

**Approach 3:** Similar to **2**, but instead of overwriting build rules, you could [add](http://www.runscriptbuildphase.com) a script that is executed during compilation, by defining a [Build Phase](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaRunScriptBuildPhase.html). The challenge here is to find all relevant classes that the target uses. You could manually inspect the [`.pbxproj` file](http://michele.io/the-project-file-part-1) to get that information (not really recommended, but a nice exercise), or use a library like [mod-pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj) (Python) or [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) (Ruby). Then proceed with the validation as in approach 2.

**Approach 4:** You could also implement a Clang extension by adding a compiler flag and code to check the prefix. This could be done by modifying the compiler itself, by adding an analyzer plugin, or writing a Clang-based tool (which could be called from a script as in approaches 2/3). This is not trivial, but can be done. [eero](http://eerolanguage.org) and [this](https://bitbucket.org/shagedorn/custum-clang-export-unsafe-api-usage) modified Clang compiler can be used as examples if you want to take this path.

Recommended reading:
[objc.io: The Build Process](http://www.objc.io/issue-6/build-process.html)
[Xcode Project vs. Xcode Workspace - Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences/)