# How to keep project available after changing the location of imported project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two projects A and B in same location (Desktop). I imported/added project B into Project A. If I move project B's location to some other folder, then the project B and associated files are not avalable inside Project A as shown in below screen. I had set `other linker flags` as `"-ObjC"` as well. Can you please help me on it.

[image]

Comment: have you copy that project(APP1) in your current project(APP2) ???

Comment: I tried with drag & drop and "Add New Files" option as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per new project copy in another project please follow below steps:

**step 1:** drag & drop your file into source project.

**step 2:** while drag its ask for make new copy at targeted project as mention below screen shot.

> ```
> if you want to copy that file check checkbox [copy item if needed].
> if you just copy that file uncheck checkbox [copy item if needed].
> ```

[image]

by doing this if you copy your project it will permanently copy in your targeted project and while you move your main project copied project also moved to another place and its work as expected.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I do not see this prompt screen when I add/drag & drop project into another project. Do I need to set any settings?

Comment: no there is no setting for this try to add root folder of that project (app1).

Comment: No. I do not see any prompt screen while adding project.

Comment: have you try with ROOT folder drag & drop in your project ?

Comment: If you drag & drop ROOT folder then you will get a problem with file duplication. Have ever tried drag & drop ROOT folder of subproject into main project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126612/discussion-between-ganesh-guturi-and-codechanger).