# React Native iOS - GoogleToolboxforMac not found

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

I've been looking for a solution for this one but failed to find one. Looking at the attachment below, why is the `GoogleToolboxforMac` in and Protobuf in red? Do I need to link them somehow? Because when I build the `.xcodeproj` it errors out saying:

> Framework GoogletoolboxforMac not found.

But when i build the `.xworkspace` file it builds fine.

[image: Screenshoot]

Comment: Have a look about workspace vs project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the workspace file, it must be inside a pod as dependence (the googletoolboxformac)

Comment: yea its in the pods folder but its in red. same with the Protobuf folder. what does it indicate? when i do pod install, it says using GoogletoolboxforMac, does it mean its already installed right? so why is it still in red?

Comment: when you do the pod install it will do everything needed so you can use it. not sure why it is in red, but it should work if you install the pods.

Comment: ill try to delete the ios folder again and run react-native upgrade. and pod install again