# Is there any equivalent of a gradle module on an iOS project?

Tags: android, ios, module

On an Android project, I can set up my gradle build file like so:

```
dependencies {
     implementation project(':mymodule')
     implementation "com.mypackage:my-other-module:1.0"
}
```

Where "mymodule" is part of my project and is usually in a subfolder of my main app root, and "my-other-module" works like an external library that was pre-built with `./gradlew install`.

As far as I understood, I could use cocoapods on an iOS project to achieve a similar setup as importing "my-other-module" on Android. But I can't think of a way to setup my project in a similar fashion as importing "mymodule" as a submodule of my app project.

To clarify, I'm not trying to reuse code between Android and iOS, nor use Gradle on iOS. All I'm looking for is finding a setup on iOS to organize my project in submodules like I would on Android.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe reading this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences

Comment: Thanks! That means a "module" in gradle world would simply be a subproject where its target is added to the main project. Is that analogy correct?

Comment: If it is only for this project, that would seem to do the job.