# No such module 'AWSMobileClient' error inside AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to link aws frameworks with a native app. I'm using cocoapods and I have included and installed the dependencies I'll need as such inside my `Podfile`

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'auth' do

    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'AWSMobileClient'
    pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn'
    pod 'AWSAuthUI'
  # Pods for auth

  target 'authTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'auth-tvOS' do

  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for auth-tvOS

  target 'auth-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

At this time, when I `import AWSMobileClient` in my `AppDelegate.swift` file I received this error.

`No such module 'AWSMobileClient'`

I'm not sure what's causing this error when yet I have other AWS frameworks that do not yield any error. This might also explain why the app build keeps failing when ran in xcode. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did the pod install successfully? Are you sure you are opening .xcworkspace not .xcodeproj in the IDE?

Comment: AWSMobileClient sdk is written in objective C. First you should add it to bridging header and than use it.

Comment: @MahbubMorshedProttoy - Yea pod installed successfully. I just realized I was working in .xcodeproj in the IDE. Probably missed that note in the documentation. Any reason in particular I should have opened .xcworkspace ?

Comment: After installing pods you have to open .xcworkspace not .xcodeproj to have access the pods. The pods are placed inside the workspace.

Comment: @ArronJ.Linton Do you want me to add my previous comment as an Answer so that you can accept it?

Comment: @PardeepBishnoi - Oh right that makes sense. I'll throw that in, see if it works. Do you have any resources that explain this in further detail ?

Comment: @ArronJ.Linton Actually if you use use_frameworks! you won't need a bridging header. In this case you are fine as user_framworks is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing the pods you need to open the .xcworkspace You cannot access them from your .xcodeproj

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21631534/413877) is a good summary of the difference between Xcode project and Xcode Workspace.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Xcode 9.2, with Swift 3.2.
At first I would gain the same "No such module 'AWSMobileClient'" error in AppDelegate.swift file.

My Solution:

1. Be sure to open the .xcworkspace file
2. In your project settings go to the build phase and add the proper frameworks. I added all the AWS frameworks, and it worked for me. 
   [Here is a Screenshot of Build Phase Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab0w6.png)

Comment: This second step is important it seems

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer above me of @Stephen Kwan [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48572298/3941896]

My problem was when I copied+pasted redundant target in the podfile. it looked like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target :'RM1' do
    use_frameworks!
    # other pods
    pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.6.6'
end

target 'RM1' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RM1

  target 'RM1Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'RM1UITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Once I combined the 2 `target: 'RM1'`, run `pod install`
and it worked.