# iOS what is the advantage and disadvantage in multiple project in one workspace

Tags: ios

There are some modules in one workspace such as login module, user register module. It belongs its own project. Other modules call them. But what is the advantage and disadvantage in multiple project in one workspace

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences.

Comment: @Martin R thanks. But I think the answer you provided means what project and workspace are. I still don't know why use this. Just for code re-use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Project vs. Xcode Workspace - Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631313/xcode-project-vs-xcode-workspace-differences)

Comment: The answer also covers what you're asking. They say that projects are sufficient in most cases and workspaces should be used only if really necessary, with the exception of CocoaPods, that *requires* you to use workspaces (in fact, it does that for you at the moment you initialize it). "Really necessary", at least in my experience, means "only if you are working on a complex environment covering multiple apps sharing some non-trivial functionalities". Other than that, a single project should be good for you

Comment: @il3v thanks. I should look into it carefully