# react-native ios build error - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

We are trying to put an iOS build using react native but our build got stuck with the below error. kindly help us resolve this issue.

we are using cocoapods: 1.8.4 version

ld: library not found for -lCocoaAsyncSocket 
[sshexec] [exec] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [sshexec] [exec] [sshexec] [exec] ** ARCHIVE FAILED ** [sshexec] [exec] [sshexec] [exec] [sshexec] [exec] The following build commands failed: [sshexec] [exec] Ld /Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spm_mobile-awskmlvxgyrsozddnaorzehbvupe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/spm_mobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spm_mobile.build/Release-iphoneos/spm_mobile.build/Objects-normal/armv7/spm_mobile normal armv7 [sshexec] [exec] Ld /Users/macbuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spm_mobile-awskmlvxgyrsozddnaorzehbvupe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/spm_mobile/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spm_mobile.build/Release-iphoneos/spm_mobile.build/Objects-normal/arm64/spm_mobile normal arm64 [sshexec] [exec] (2 failures) [sshexec] [exec] + GenerateArchive [sshexec] [exec] + /Applications/Xcode_11_3_1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
    -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /Users/macbuild/WH_DIR/Apr_20_2020/SPM_MOBILE_IOS/3025072/MACSRC/build/profiles/Appstore/exportOptions.plist -archivePath /Users/macbuild/WH_DIR/Apr_20_2020/SPM_MOBILE_IOS/3025072/MACSRC/build/../ios/spm_mobile.xcarchive
    -exportPath /Users/macbuild/WH_DIR/Apr_20_2020/SPM_MOBILE_IOS/3025072/MACSRC/build/../ios/spm_mobile.xcarchive/Products/Applications [sshexec] [exec] ** EXPORT FAILED ** [sshexec] [exec] [sshexec] [exec] error: archive not found at path '/Users/macbuild/WH_DIR/Apr_20_2020/SPM_MOBILE_IOS/3025072/MACSRC/ios/spm_mobile.xcarchive' [sshexec] [exec] Result: 65 [sshexec] [echo] ExitValue from the task is : 65

Comment: Ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but was when I built a game in unity and when searching the problem didn't really find anything but what worked for me was instead of using the file "xcodeproj" I used the "xcworkspace". At the time didn't really know why it worked but searching the differences of the 2 types of files I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21644948/10310808), see the last paragraph.

> CocoaPods, which automatically handles 3rd party libraries for you, uses workspaces. Therefore, you have to use them, too, when you use CocoaPods (which a lot of people do).

Comment: Which file path you are changed xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj.

Comment: It should be in the same folder