# Connect Objective-C framework to Swift iOS 8 app (Parse framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, swift

I am trying to use an Objective-C framework with the Swift programming language for iOS 8 development. This is a specific case of an import but the general problem is:

**How do you import an Objective-C framework into swift and get the import recognized?**

I am trying to integrate the Parse framework into a swift application using the iOS 8 and Xcode 6 betas.

Here is the technique for Parse framework integration in Objective-C:

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#social/mobile/ios/native/existing

I have downloaded the Parse framework as a compressed archive, extracted it, and imported it into Xcode 6 without any problems. Within my application it appears as a properly formatted framework under the name Parse.framework.

My current thought process is to modify the `AppDelegate.swift` file in the root directory of my project. Here is the current file without modifications (automatically generated by Xcode upon swift project creation):

https://gist.github.com/fconcklin/e8ef7d8b056105a04161

I have tried to import parse by adding the line `import Parse` below the line `import UIKit`. However, Xcode issues a warning that there is no such module found and the build fails.

I also tried creating a file `${PROJ_NAME_HERE}-Bridging-Header.h` that contains the Objective-C import of Parse using `import <Parse/Parse.h>`. This line doesn't throw an error but appears to ultimately make no difference.

Comment: Is the path to bridging header set in the project properties? Bring up the project properties and and look for "Objective-C Bridging Header" under the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section. Just having a bridging header file is not enough - you have to set the path to it in the project.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A "Fool Proof" way of adding a bridging header is as follows:

If you have a **Swift** project, add a new **Objective-C File** to your project and Xcode will prompt if you want to configure your project with a bridging header. Press yes.

If you have a **Objective-C** project, add a new **Swift File** to it and you will get the same prompt. Press yes.

After you get the bridging header, you can delete the file you just added if you want to.

Comment: I have a swift project, but I cannot get the add bridging header message to show up when I add a ObjC header file (xcode 6 b4). Any ideas?

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner I had the same issue until I realized I had imported another framework that already created bridging class. Could it be that you already created a bridging header class?

Comment: I tried this technique, but all I get is a blank bridging header file.

Comment: i have the bridging header ok but the framework show errors because is on objective c and Xcode 8 don't tolerate it in a swift project, what i can do?

Answer (score 80):

After further research I found the solution and realized that I was just confused.

The correct approach is as follows:

- Import your Objective C framework by dragging and dropping the framework into an Xcode 6 Swift project.
- Create a new Objective C file in your project (File->New->File [Objective C for iOS]).
- Accept the prompt (agree) to create a bridging header file between Objective C and Swift.
- Delete your newly created Objective C file but retain the bridging header file `${YOURPROJ}-Bridging-Header.h`.
- In the Bridging header file, import your framework using the standard **Objective C** import syntax (e.g. `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`).
- This relinquishes the need to perform an `import Parse` statement in your `AppDelegate.swift` file. You can now write code that utilizes whatever framework as long as it is imported using the bridging header. It is available throughout your project's Swift files.

Now, if you would like to test Parse integration in your project, you can type `Parse.` and use code completion to browse the framework and see that the code completion is indicative of a successful import.

However, there is another caveat here that needs to be addressed when using a Bridging Header file. All dependencies of the framework need to be specified in the Bridging Header file as well. In the case of integrating Parse framework into a Swift application your Bridging Header file will look like this:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 // Parse Dependencies
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
 #import <CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h>
 #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
 #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
 #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
 #import <Security/Security.h>
 #import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
 #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>

 // Import parse framework
 #import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this reply it really works, the thing is that is very tricky to realise that you won't have to import Parse in your swift files!

Comment: When I do this and go to another Swift file, I get "SourceKitService Crashed.  Editor function temporarily limited" endlessly until I remove the header.

Comment: Does it still works? I get `failed to import bridging header '/PATH/TO/File-Bridging-Header.h' ` and then `error: 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found
`

Answer (score 10):

To add Parse framework to the Swift project:
Add this libaries to the Swift Project.

[image]

Paste this frameworks from ParseSDK to your project:

[image]

Add a ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24272431/1847511) file with such content.

[image]

Add path to tie bridging header:

[image]

Add the TestCode:

[image]

Run the app.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Objective-C Classes in Swift**

If you are going to import code within an App Target (Mixing Swift and Objective-C in one project) you should use `bridging header` file to expose Objective-C code to Swift code. [<sup>[Mixing Swift and Objective-C code in a project]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

In this post I will describe how to import Objective-C framework to Swift code

### Swift consumer -> Objective-C dynamic framework

Xcode version 10.2.1

### Create Objective-C framework

Create a framework project or create a framework target

```
File -> New -> Project... -> Cocoa Touch Framework
//or
Project editor -> Add a Target -> Cocoa Touch Framework
```

Two files will be generated:

1. `Info.plist` - `Build Settings -> Info.plist File`
2. `<product_name>.h` - `Build Phases -> Headers`. It is umbrella header file which will be open for consumer[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57481319/4770877)

Add all `.h` files to this umbrella file(<product_name>.h)

```
#import "header_1.h"
#import "header_2.h"
```

Add Implementation files `.m`

```
Select `.m` file -> Select File Inspectors Tab -> Target Membership -> Select the target
//or
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add files
```

Add Headers files `.h` that were listed in `<product_name>.h` in public zone (`header_1.h`, `header_2.h`)[<sup>[can not do it]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511627/4770877) [<sup>[public target membership]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57467721/4770877)

```
Select `.h` file -> Select File Inspectors Tab -> Target Membership -> Select the target and make it **public**
//or
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Phases -> Headers -> add files to the **public** zone
```

Build the framework - <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or `Product -> Build`

Note: Be sure that you build the framework for the same process architecture as the client code.

Find generated output[<sup>[Build location]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512068/4770877)

```
Products group -> <product_name>.framework -> Show in Finder
```

The framework includes

- `Info.plist`
- `Modules` folder with:
- `module.modulemap`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57355596/4770877) [<sup>[Custom modulemap]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665560/4770877) This file was autogenerated because `Build Settings -> Defines Module -> YES`
- `Headers` folder with:
- files from `Headers` section. There are public interfaces/definitions

[image]

### Swift consumer with Objective-C framework

`Drag and drop` the binary into the Xcode project[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57708587/4770877)

`Embed binaries`[<sup>[Library not loaded]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216681/4770877) [<sup>[Link vs Embed]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57500697/4770877)

```
Project editor -> select a target -> General -> Embedded Binaries -> path to `<product_name>.framework` file
```

I will automatically add the framework to:

1. `Project editor -> select a target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries`
2. `Project editor -> select a target -> Build Phases -> Embed Frameworks`
3. `Project editor -> select a target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`

Add `Framework Search paths(FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS)`[<sup>[Module not found]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216466/4770877) [<sup>[Recursive path]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516845/4770877)

```
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Framework Search paths -> add path to the parent of `<product_name>.framework` file
```

Import module to the Swift client code[<sup>[module_name]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57517400/4770877)

```
import module_name
```

[More examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)

Comment: How do we consume an Objective-C xcframework in a Swift Framework? using module map.
I have this:
'module ObjCHyperPayModule {
    header "../Frameworks/OPPWAMobile.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/OPPWAMobile.framework/Headers/OPPWAMobile.h"
//    header "../Frameworks/OPPWAMobile.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/OPPWAMobile.framework/Headers/OPPWAMobile.h"
//${SRCROOT}
    export *
}'

Answer (score 3):

The answer for my problem was different. I had the **Framework Search Paths in my project's Build Settings** set to *recursive* when they should have been *non-recursive*.

In my case, my target has its Framework Search Paths set to **$(inherited)**, which means to inherit the setting from my project.

My project's Framework Search Paths only had one path, **$PROJECT_DIR/../External/**** (with the two asteriks meaning "search this folder recursively". My **Parse.framework** file was located in the base level of the External folder.

Changing the path from *recursive* to *non-recursive* fixed things for me. Very strange...

Answer (score 1):

New Parse framework version need some update.

Such as You should insert libsqlite3.0.dylib in Library Binary With Libraries and update header file with #import  and #import