# Xcode 6 - Could not build module 'Accelerate'

Tags: ios, xcode, accelerate-framework

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 2 (6A216f) and everything was okay, but when I build to any device other than the 5s I get 111 errors.
The problem occurs because I'm using the [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) and it imports the Accelerate framework.

I've searched a lot and could not find any solution. This is the error:

[It's too long so I uploaded to pastebin.](http://pastebin.com/vTqDvhCK)

PS: I don't know which part you need so I uploaded everything.

Also if I remove #import "FXBlurView.h" from the Bridging-Header I get no errors

EDIT: <strike>So I "solved" my problem. The error says that the compiler doesn't know what vFloat was, so I checked vecLibTypes.h and saw that vFloat was defined in this piece of code:</strike>

```
#elif defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__)
#ifdef __SSE__
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#include <xmmintrin.h>
typedef float                   vFloat          __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16)));
#else /* not __GNUC__ */
#include <xmmintrin.h>
typedef __m128                          vFloat;
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
#endif  /* defined(__SSE__) */
```

and If I remove the first #elif I get no errors...

EDIT2: The correct solution was found by @Nick

Comment: You have to import Accelerate framework above the import of `FXBlurView` in the bridging-header. See the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272184/connect-objective-c-framework-to-swift-ios-8-app-parse-framework

Comment: Changed my file bridging file to:
#import <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Availability.h>
#import "FXBlurView.h"

And it still doesn't work

Comment: Looking at your log, it seems the error is `unknown type name 'vFloat'; did you mean 'float'` that is occuring on non 64-bit devices. Is there somewhere in the code that defines `vFloat` only for arm64?

Comment: I believe that vFload is defined in vecLibTypes.h that is inside Accelerate framework

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with the Accelerate framework being linked in my own iOS Framework built with Xcode6 where some symbols are not being linked correctly (vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888 to be precise)

Comment: I am also having this issue - is this a bug on Apple's part?

Comment: I think it's a bug. In the middle of my project, my Xcode stuck on indexing files. After I removed some of the code, it finally stopped endless indexing process but the compiler started complaining exactly the same above.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed in Xcode 6 Beta 3. Finally :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the Accelerate import statement inside the implementation file it works.  I forked the project to make the change and have submitted a pull request.

https://github.com/nrbrook/fxblurview

Comment: I was still having the issue in Beta 3 and your solution fixed it for me. Thanks

Comment: Coming back to this with Xcode 6β5. Seems like this is no longer an issue.