# No Such Module 'Ensembles' Error - importing objective-c framework to use in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, ensembles

I am add Ensembles to my Swift project - found here https://github.com/drewmccormack/ensembles. I have had no luck adding iCloud support to my app and syncing data across devices so hoping this will work.

I have followed the following instructions for adding the framework to my app,

1. In Finder, drag the Ensembles iOS.xcodeproj project from the
   Framework directory into your Xcode project.
2. Select your App's project root in the source list on the left, and then select the App's target.
3. In the General tab, click the + button in the Linked
   Frameworks and Libraries section.
4. Choose the libensembles.a library and add it.
5. Select the Build Settings tab. Locate the Other Linker
   Flags setting, and add the flag -ObjC.

   This is how it looks in my project, I am unsure if i have done this step right.

[image]

6. Select the Build Phases tab.
   Open Target Dependencies, and click the + button.
7. Locate the
   Ensembles Resources iOS product, and add that as a dependency.
8. Open the Ensembles iOS.xcodeproj project in the source list, and open the Products group.
9. Drag the Ensembles.bundle product into the Copy
   Bundle Resources build phase of your app.
10. Add the following import in your precompiled header file, or in any files using Ensembles.

It is step 10 that I am having problems with. Do I have to create a bridging header or just import the framework into my swift files ?

This is how I am importing within my `CoreDataStack.swift` file

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Ensembles

class CoreDataStack: NSObject, CDEPersistentStoreEnsembleDelegate {

}
```

This gives me the error;

> No such module 'Ensembles'

I tried creating a bridging header by doing the following;

- Add new header file
- Import Ensembles

This is how that looks;

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h
#import <Ensembles/Ensembles.h>

#endif /* Header_h */
```

But still no luck, does anybody know where I am going wrong when trying to import the framework to use with my swift project ?

Comment: Swift, on Darwin, likes libraries in frameworks. It looks like the Ensembles project doesn't provide an iOS framework, making using it on iOS a bit of a pain. Try opening an issue, requesting an iOS framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a bridging header you do not need to use import.

However I don't think you may be adding a bridging header correctly, go to, file, new, file, add a objective-C file and a dialog should pop up asking if you want to create a bridging header. Add both files but delete the objective-C file and keep the bridging header.

Then import the ensembles framework to the bridging header like so.

```
#import <Ensembles/Ensembles.h>
```

When creating a bridging file successfully you should not need to import the framework in your swift files and it should be available throughout your project. See this post for more information - [Connect Objective C framework to Swift iOS 8 app (Parse framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272184/connect-objective-c-framework-to-swift-ios-8-app-parse-framework)