# IOS Module not found error when adding Objective-C framework projects using CocoaPods as a module in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-framework

I have scenario where i have couple of SDKs and a test app. Here is the example.

**SDKCore** - “Objective-C Framework”

**SDKUI** - “Objective-C Framework”

- SDKCore is added as a dependency using Cocoapods `pod 'SDKCore', :path => '../SDKCore'` and with flag ‘use_frameworks’
- SDKUIViewController uses methods from SDKCore. I’m importing like this `@import SDKCore;`

Code

```
#import "SDKUIViewController.h"
@import SDKCore;

@interface SDKUIViewController ()

@end

@implementation SDKUIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [SDKClass hitTest];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

**SDKTestSwift**

- SDKCore is added as a dependency using Cocoapods `pod 'SDKCore', :path => '../SDKCore'` and with flag ‘use_frameworks’
- SDKUI is added as a dependency using Cocoapods `pod 'SDKUI', :path => '../SDKUI'` and with flag ‘use_frameworks’

**Problem**
is when i compile SDKTestSwift I’m getting `Module SDKCore not found`a compile error on one of the files from SDKUI (See attached) 
[image]

Really got stuck here. Thanks a lot in advance.

You can [download the sample project from here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/176318311/FrameworkTest.zip).

Comment: Why dont u just import the headers? I think Cocoapods doesnt support modules for pod with only headers/static lib/framework

Comment: i tried with headers '#import <SDKCore/SDKClass.h>' but same issue `SDKUI` works fine no errors and in `SDKTestSwift` i am getting this error `SDKCore/SDKClass.h  file not found`

Comment: and i have to use modules because Im using ObjectiveC pods in Swift project.

Comment: In swift you MUST create `bridging-header` file and import header file there in order to use obj-c in swift, another suggestion is that create an empty class (visible .m file) to make the pod generate modules, but it will create confusing for your user

Comment: I think module do the bridging-header thing... i think that's way if i use SDKCore in app directly it works. Problem comes when i use SDKCore in SDKUI and use SDKUI in app.

Comment: Just try create bridging-header in your swift project and import the header there, see if it works

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: Make sure you create the file properly, like in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438455/no-such-module-ensembles-error-importing-objective-c-framework-to-use-in-swi?rq=1)

Comment: Still its not working..... whenever you have time please have a look at the sample project. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I actually have misunderstood you from the start, your issue lying in your pod, not project, this happen because you didn't state that the `SDKUI` depend on `SDKCore`, thats why you cant use any code from `SDKCore`

To fix this, simply add `s.dependency 'SDKCore'` in your `SDKUI.podspec` and run `pod install` again, then it works

Comment: It's working... Thanks a lot!... Really appreciate your time.