# import IOKit in Swift returns me no such module

Tags: c++, swift, iokit

I've got an iPadOS project where I'm using a C++ class to work with devices connected via USB. This class uses `IOServiceMatching` among other methods.

I'm trying to convert the C++ class to Swift but when I'm try to use `IOServiceMatching` it doesn't find it, so I thought the problem would be importing the module `IOKit`

When I import it with `import IOKit` I get `No such module IOKit`

I know the framework is imported fine because I'm using it in C++ and the functionality
in C++ works fine.

am I missing something?

Comment: You would need to manually add the framework to the project. And then you can follow this guide to create a bridging header: [Connect Objective-C framework to Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272184/connect-objective-c-framework-to-swift-ios-8-app-parse-framework)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719564

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why this time I didn't think to look into apple developer forum.