# Opensource App Extension Swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I have created a custom UI for a share extension in an app I am working on. I was wondering if there was a way to export this as a framework/library for others to use via cocoapods? Essentially I want others to use my library as a way for custom UI for share extensions

I have no experience in creating libraries so if this is possible, can anyone recommend how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want others to JUST be able to use it or do you want it to really be open source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an .a static library in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125338/how-can-i-use-an-a-static-library-in-swift)