# AppRTC mach-or errors

Tags: swift, apprtc

I'm getting Mach-O errors on a clean install of AppRTC in swift.

I create a new project in xcode 8.3.3 and run.

I add:
  pod ‘AppRTC‘

to my podfile, and use pod install.

When complete, I disable bitcode.
This is running on a device, cleaned the code and I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that AppRTC does not work with Pods for Swift. For Objective-C, no problem. This is not a real solution, but I used a static library for this.

Also, does the downvoter have feedback as to why this question was not suitable?

Comment: Could you explain how can I solve by static library?

Comment: Can drag and drop the classes into your project to do this.

Comment: Or like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125338/how-can-i-use-an-a-static-library-in-swift