# How to access pure Swift Static Library from pure Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

I have a static library in Swift and I want to access this library class from another Swift project. The class in the library cannot be referred properly.

My static library called `StaticLib` contains hierarchy,

#### Static Library Project - Hierarchy

```
StaticLib (project)
   StaticLib 
       StaticLib.swift
   Products
       libStaticLib.a
```

---

#### Static Library Project  - StaticLib.swift

```
public class StaticLib {

    public class func test(string: String) {
        Printer().printMe(string: string)
    }
}

class Printer {

    func printMe(string: String){
        print("This is test tring: \(string)")
    }
}
```

#### Host App - AppDelegate.swift

```
import StaticLib

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        StaticLib.test("How do you do?") // error

        return true
    }
}
```

#### Steps I Have Done -

1. Click project in Xcode Project Navigator
2. Click **+** to add new target
3. Select **Frameworks & Libraries > Static Library > Next**
4. Enter name `StaticLib` (in Swift) > Finish
5. Open StaticLib.swift and enter

```
    public class StaticLib {

        public class func test(string: String) {
            Printer().printMe(string: string)
        }
    }

    class Printer {

        func printMe(string: String){
            print("This is test tring: \(string)")
        }
    }
```

6. Select `StaticLib` schema, **Build > OK**
7. Copy the `libStaticLib.a` into a new folder called `HostApp/Libs/`
8. Select project in Project Navigator > click main application target > select General
9. In section **Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content** click I see `libStaticLib.a` is already added by Xcode intelligence
10. Select main app schema > Build > OK
11. Select AppDelegate.swift > add `import StaticLib`
12. Add

```
    StaticLib.test("How do you do?")
```

12. Try to Build

#### Compilation Error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'StaticLib'

**How can I resolve this issue? Do I need to create any header file in library?**

**Note:** I have embedded the `libStaticLib.a` successfully and it's present in Host apps `General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded contents` tab.

Comment: Did you do `import StaticLib` in your `AppDelegate`? Also, the `test` function needs to be `public` as well.

Comment: @DávidPásztor when I `import StaticLib` it gives `No such module 'StaticLib'`

Comment: Have you already tried the steps from [How can I use a static library in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125338/how-can-i-use-an-a-static-library-in-swift)

Comment: @david i am working with pure swift library for pure swift host app so i did not add any header file. If i need to what should be the content of library header? Also the reference posts didn’t discuss about my situation.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have made the class function public.

Comment: please see updated full steps in answer (repeated from scratch)

Comment: updated for the case of different projects, in short - you need also to import swift module for your static library and make it visible in swift search paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've passed your steps and all works, at least at Xcode 11.3.1 / iOS 13.3. The only thing... it seems... see comment

```
import StaticLib // << looks like you've forgot this one !!!

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        StaticLib.test("How do you do?") // error

        return true
    }
}
```

**Update:** Here are my steps -

1. Click project in Xcode Project Navigator
2. Click **+** to add new target
3. Select **Frameworks & Libraries > Static Library > Next**
4. Enter name `StaticLib` (in Swift) > Finish
5. Open StaticLib.swift and enter

```
    public class StaticLib {
        public class func printme() {
            print("I'm swfit static lib!")
        }
    }
```

6. Select `StaticLib` schema, **Build > OK**
7. Select project in Project Navigator > click main application target > select General
8. In section **Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content** click **+** and select `libStaticLib.a` > Add
9. Select main app schema > Build > OK
10. Select AppDelegate.swift > add `import StaticLib`
11. Add anywhere in code

```
    StaticLib.printme()
```

12. Build > OK > Run ... see output

**Update2:** for external Lib project

+1 It is needed to copy `StaticLib.swiftmodule` (it is created at the same place as libStaticLib.a) into target project folder (I placed it at the level of `.xcodeproj` file)

+2 In main application target `Build Settings` set `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = ${SRCROOT}`

+3 Clean > Build

Note: the indicator that module is loaded is autocompletion for import - it should show StaticLib

Comment: How did you add the library? Drag and drop or moved to location physically and refer it? Did u change anything in build setting? I am getting error. See comment in post.

Comment: In step 8, it does not show the `libStaticLib.a`, unless I copy it into a folder in host app.  Do I need to do that? However, if I copy the library its already shown in General tab. Note that both library and host app are not in same workspace. My Xcode version: 11.0 (11A420a)

Comment: I have updated the post with all the steps I have done. Please see.