# Create a CocoaPod Swift Framework by adding Objective C Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks, bridging-header

I want to integrate my ObjectiveC Static Library into my Cococapod framework which is in swift.My objective C Static Library is not uploaded on CocoaPod. I want to add it without creating a pod.

I created a Swift Framework in Xcode and followed the below given link to import my static library [How can I use an .a static library in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125338/how-can-i-use-an-a-static-library-in-swift/59215981#59215981) . Xcode generates a header file in which I have added my import.

I created a Swift Framework using CocoaPods procedure.
I added my Static Library manually into the Pods Directory.

Question One : In my CocoaPods framework there is no such header file so where can I add my objective c imports.
Question Two : Is this the right place to add any external dependency?

I need to use my classes which are written in Objective C into Swift Framework.

To better understand the problem I created an Objective C class into the Swift Framework. This class was able to import the Objective C class. But my swift class was not able to.

Clearly we cannot create bridging headers in frameworks. So how do I do this?

Comment: Add the static library as a git submodule of your swift framework git repo.

Comment: @trojanfoe.....I have not uploaded my swift source on git.....Can I import the static library into my swift framework?

Comment: You should get a GitHub account and keep your projects in private repos.  They can then be easily shared with other projects and other people.  Not to mention the benefit of source control itself.

Comment: I understand the advantages of using source control. The reason why I am creating a CocoaPod framework is I have two dependencies one of my static library and another pod framework. So I could either create a pod from my static library and add both the pods as dependencies or add my static library manually. Is that possible?