# What is export * in module.modulemap file inside each framework?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, frameworks, module-map

I have created a framework named `Communication`. Inside the framework's container, there is a `module.modulemap` file which has the following contents:

```
framework module Communication {
    umbrella header "Communication.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}
```

I can understand that the module declares an umbrella header to expose it to the containing application/target.

What is the meaning of other two lines of code?

```
export *
module * { export * }
```

What are these lines exporting?

Comment: Check this [doc on LLVM modules](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#export-declaration) too.

Comment: Both of the links are helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Objective-C Module Map(.modulemap) for Objective-C and Swift**

Objective-C language exposes API through .modulemap for Objective-C and Swift languages

[[ObjC Module]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213796/4770877)

[[Custom .modulemap]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665560/4770877)

It is about [LLVM Modules and Module Map Language](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language). `Modulemap` exposes **C header files** for **external** binaries. It is a bridge between module and headers. Modulemap helps to convert `#include, #import -> @import` because it has a mapping between module name and headers inside. Also modulemap helps to create standalone **additional** modules and submodules. Modulemap can contains a lot of modules(only one has to have the same name as product name) and a lot of submodules

```
//Objective-C exposes API through .modulemap for Objective-C and Swift

.h.m uses .h.m = Objective-C consumer, Objective-C producer = .modulemap
.swift uses .h.m = Swift consumer, Objective-C producer = .modulemap
```

Framework which includes `.modulemap` is called `Modular Framework`. Path:

```
module_name.framework/Modules/module_name.modulemap
```

[image]

**Setup**

- When you create a library[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215981/4770877) you should create and setup it manually
- When you create a framework[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216086/4770877) it is setup automatically

Even if you create Swift framework Xcode automatically creates modulemap

[[Mixing Objective-C and Swift in the same Application]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217109/4770877)

Comment: This does not answer what `export` means.

Comment: @ray, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704268/no-umbrella-header-found-for-target-module-map-will-not-be-generated/57665560#57665560

Answer (score 2):

What helped me get my head around the `export` and `module` keywords in `modulemap` files was to play around with them. I found the [Clang > Modules](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) documentation difficult to understand. I'll summarise some of the experiments that I ran<sup>1</sup> to give you a feel for what the `export` and `module` keywords mean in practice. I found the behaviour of the `modulemap` file to be different in Objective-C and Swift code so I'll cover both separately.

Let's assume your `Communication.h` header file consists of the following two imports:

```
#import <Communication/Class1.h>
#import <Communication/Class2.h>
```

Assume also that `Class1.h` defines a single class named `Class1` and `Class2.h` defines a single class named `Class2`.

## Importing modules in Objective-C classes

Let's assume, to start with, that your `modulemap` file is defined minimally as follows:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
}
```

In the Objective-C classes of your targets which link in the `Communication` framework, you can import the `Communication` module and you can call on the classes imported via the `Communication.h` umbrella header file, as follows:

```
@import Communication;

+ (void)someMethodThatDependsOnTheCommunicationModule {
    [Class1 someOperation];
    [Class2 someOperation];
}
```

What you can't do right now is import the `Communication.Class1` sub-module. To make that possible, you need to change your `modulemap` file to the following:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
  
  module Class1 {
      header "Class1.h"
  }
}
```

You can now import the `Communication.Class1` sub-module and call on `Class1`, as follows:

```
@import Communication.Class1;

+ (void)someMethodThatDependsOnTheCommunicationModule {
    [Class1 someOperation];
}
```

Of course, you still can't import the `Communication.Class2` sub-module. To make that possible, you can either add a `Class2` module declaration in the `modulemap` file like we did for `Class1` or use a wildcard<sup>2</sup>. Here's how you would do it with the wildcard:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
  
  module * {}
}
```

With this change, you can now import the `Communication.Class1` and `Communication.Class2` sub-modules and you can call on their classes, as follows:

```
@import Communication.Class1;
@import Communication.Class2;

+ (void)someMethodThatDependsOnTheCommunicationModule {
    [Class1 someOperation];
    [Class2 someOperation];
}
```

I tried my best to find a use for the `export` keyword in the context of modules that will be imported into Objective-C code but I was unable to.

## Importing modules in Swift classes

Let's assume, to start with, that your `modulemap` file is defined minimally as follows:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
}
```

In the Swift classes of your targets which link in the `Communication` framework, you can import the `Communication` module and you can call on the classes imported via the `Communication.h` umbrella header file, as follows:

```
import Communication

func someFunctionThatDependsOnTheCommunicationModule {
    Class1.someOperation()
    Class2.someOperation()
}
```

What you can't do right now is import the `Communication.Class1` sub-module. To make that possible, you need to change your `modulemap` file to the following:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
  
  module Class1 {}
}
```

You can now import the `Communication.Class1` sub-module and call on `Class1`, as follows:

```
import Communication.Class1

func someFunctionThatDependsOnTheCommunicationModule {
    Class1.someOperation()
}
```

Contrary to what I experienced with Objective-C<sup>3</sup>, I found that I was still able to call on `Class2` despite importing `Communication.Class1` only.

If you still want to import `Communication.Class2` in isolation<sup>4</sup>, you can either add a `Class2` module declaration in the `modulemap` file like we did for `Class1` or use a wildcard<sup>2</sup>. Here's how you would do it with the wildcard:

```
framework module Communication {
  umbrella header "Communication.h"
  
  module * {}
}
```

I tried my best to find a use for the `export` keyword in the context of modules that will be imported into Swift code but I was unable to.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I ran these experiments in Xcode 13.4.1. If you experience different behaviour in a later version of Xcode, let me know and I will re-run my experiments and update my answer.

<sup>2</sup>The wildcard will define a module for every class that's defined by the headers imported in the umbrella header file.

<sup>3</sup>And contrary to what I expected.

<sup>4</sup>Despite it being quite pointless as explained in the previous paragraph.</sup>