# XCode: Copy Headers: Public vs. Private vs. Project and symbolcation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a Cocoa Touch Static Library that is used by my iPhone app.  This library is included as a sub project so that I can build them at the same time while working on them.

Based on this article:
[XCode: Copy Headers: Public vs. Private vs. Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439192/xcode-copy-headers-public-vs-private-vs-project) Its recommended to put all my header files in the Project section, however doing that breaks symbolication on crashes.  If I archive and install the app and it crashes Xcode is unable to symbolicate the file even with the .DSYM file present.  If I delete everything out of the projects section I can symbolicate just fine.

My questions are

1) Is there any harm with not putting my headers in the project section?  This article said my app would launch faster, however I dont notice any kind of speed difference. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html

2) Is there a way I can put them in the Project section and still get symbolication to work.

Not sure this matters, but I am using XCode 4.3.2 and iOS 5.1