# xcode - types of header files in libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, header-files

[XCode: Copy Headers: Public vs. Private vs. Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439192/xcode-copy-headers-public-vs-private-vs-project/8016333)

That seems to be a good explanation but i still couldn't understand much of it.

public - readable source code? do they mean readable source code of the header file?

private - since i am still working on that part of the implementation, i'll mark that header as private and no one will be able to use it, until i change it back to public and build the library again. ??

project -  I couldn't understand anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: if you want to make your code available as a library, put those function and type declarations in the header.

If you have complicated code that shares types between `c` files and requires-forward declaration of types and functions, put them in headers.

Otherwise, no *need* to use headers. Although it's nice to separate them out for readibility and documentation purposes.

Comment: i want to use my code as a library and thus i will use headers. I am just confused about the 'type' of headers. Public private and Project. In the project settings we have an option of setting the type of header